# JQ combine array of json maps based on keys

Tags: json, key, jq

My json looks like the following

```
[
  {
    "100": "ONE",
    "200": "TWO"
  },
  {
    "100": "1",
    "200": "2"
  }
]
```

and I am expecting the following output

```
{
  "1": "ONE",
  "2": "TWO"
}
```

I found few answers here but all have static keys but in my case keys are dynamic

Another example

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "data": {
    "bac6f56f-101c-26da-edfa-c08e6622a337": "1"
  },
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {
      "bac6f56f-101c-26da-edfa-c08e6622a337": "restart"
    },
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-06-25T14:53:06Z",
    "uid": "7b1dfc3a-1357-400e-b750-a1ff98a204b9"
  }
}
```

and the expected output is

```
{"restart":"1"}
```

Comment: Are keys always sorted?

Comment: No that was an example

Comment: What is the expected output for the above?

Comment: @Inian added another example and it is an output of kubectl get configmap

Comment: @Inian {"restart":"1"}

Comment: @SanchuVarkey: Remember that your examples are not similar. If your second is the right one, remove the earlier one

Comment: Yeah, I realized that .. I was trying to simplify things but it may cause confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
. as [$V, $K]
| reduce ($K | keys_unsorted)[] as $k ({};
  . + {($K[$k]): $V[$k]}
)
```

This iterates over the second object's keys, retrieves values associated with each key in both objects, and pairs them in a new one. And can be adapted for your second example by changing

```
. as [$V, $K]
```

to

```
. as {data: $V, metadata: {annotations: $K}}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e-DZOWmrTj)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reduce-free solution to the first problem that hopefully also elucidates the general approach:

```
.[0] as $dict
| .[1]
| with_entries( {value: $dict[.key], key: (.value|tostring) } )
```

### Solution to second problem

Using the above approach, we have only to tweak the first two lines:

```
.data as $dict
| .metadata.annotations
| with_entries( {value: $dict[.key], key: (.value|tostring) } )
```

Comment: if I want just a pipe-separated string as output like `restart|1` for the second problem, how would you rewrite it. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, of course. One way would be to create the appropriate array(s) and then use `join("|")`.

Comment: I piped this to your code `| keys[] as $k | "\($k)|\(.[$k])"` and it works

Comment: Where there's one way, there's usually another :-)

Comment: How would you write your way `create the appropriate array(s) and then use join("|")` ?

Comment: `| keys_unsorted[] as $k | [$k, .[$k]] | join("|")`